# Set SVG boundaries

Tags: animation, svg

may I know how can I measure the width and length of my SVG size? From there, I would like to restrain and limit all the image elements to move only within the SVG.

My SVG name is "main", how can I set bouncing area so that when the images reaches the side it wont moves out from the area?

Currently if i set more images to appear on the SVG, somehow it will move out of the SVG. Is there a way to check it?

```
      <!-- ******************** Animation ******************** -->  

        $(window).load(function(){
        $(document).ready(function(e) {
        var num = 0;
        var interval;


        $('#add').click(function(e) {
        $('#box').append('<div class="predator" id="predator'+ num + '"><img src="Pictures/PondSpecies/anchovies.png"></div>');
        $('#predator'+num).css({
        left: randomRange(500,150),
        top: randomRange(400,150)
        });

        if (interval)
        clearInterval(interval);
        interval = setInterval (function () {
        for (var i=0; i<num; i++) {
            $('#predator'+i).animate ({
                    left: '+=' + randomRange(-6,7),
                    top: '+=' + randomRange(-6,7)
            }, 100);
            }
            }, 100);
            num++;
            });
            $('#remove').click(function(e) {
            num--;

            $('#predator' + num).remove();

            if (num == 0 && interval)
            clearInterval(interval);
            });
            });


            /* FUNCTIONS */
            function randomRange(min, max) {
            return Math.random() * (max-min) + min;
            }
            });  


        <!-- ******************** Animation ******************** -->
```

EDITED::

I tried to put in this 3 checks, but somehow it does not work, the checking...

```
function outOfBounds(point, boundary) {
    return point.y > boundary.top
    || point.y < boundary.bottom + 200
    || point.x < boundary.getLeftBoundAt(point.y)+500
    || point.x > boundary.getRightBoundAt(point.y)+500;
}

function getLeftBoundAt(y) {
    return this.slope * y + this.base + 300;
}

function getTopBoundAt(x) {
    var segment = this.topSegmentAt(x);
    return segment.origin.y + segment.slope * (x - segment.origin.x);
}
```

Comment: are you sure you are using SVG animations? The code you mention are simply CSS animations using jQuery method `.animate()` ...

Answer (score 1):

**First of all**, you should not have two event decalaration, but keep only one, the safest is the DOM ready event, so fom this:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
    }
}
```

use this

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
}
```

or, if you want the shortest version, you can simply use

```
$(function(e) {
}
```

---

**Second of all**, you mention SVG animation, but what I can only see in your code is simple CSS animations...

For your information, this is a CSS animation as well: http://themble.com/bones

---

Now, regarding your bounds, normally we set to the width and height of the current webpage, but this is always from the developer to know exactly what he wants from the animation, sometimes we could simply want a strip-a-like size...

assuming you have:

```
<div id="svg"></div>
```

you set the draw area as:

```
 svg = Raphael("svg", 
              $("#svg").width(), 
              $("#svg").height());
```

Note, that I'm using Raphael here just for the sake of a demonstration, you use your own library, if not using [RaphaelJs](http://raphaeljs.com/).

Comment: May I know is it possible to make the boundaries without Raphael.js or others? Just purely JS... is it possible?

Comment: boundaries of what? your CSS Animation? in a CSS animation, your set the boundaries yourself or simply use `overflow: hidden;` so it does not show anything out of the wanted area...